# In which way can I transorm pdf file in ms word doc 97 format?

Tags: libreoffice, pdf

under kubuntu 22.04 I have a pdf file and I need to make a ms word doc 97 file to edit
it under both Libre Office Writer and ms word doc 97.
If I open this file from Libre Office Writer the file is opened in Libre Office Draw application, which has no option
to save file as word doc 97 file.  In which way can I transorm my file in ms word doc 97 format ?

**PS.**
maybe not  ms word doc 97, but how to convert to MODERN(no sure which format current now)  ms word doc format?

**PS2:**
I try command and got error :

```
pandoc source.pdf -f pdf -t docx -o Agreement.doc
Unknown input format pdf
Pandoc can convert to PDF, but not from PDF.
```

In help I see :

```
pandoc -h 
pandoc [OPTIONS] [FILES]
  -f FORMAT, -r FORMAT  --from=FORMAT, --read=FORMAT                    
  -t FORMAT, -w FORMAT  --to=FORMAT, --write=FORMAT                     
  -o FILE               --output=FILE                                   
                        --data-dir=DIRECTORY                            
  -M KEY[:VALUE]        --metadata=KEY[:VALUE]                          
                        --metadata-file=FILE                            
  -d FILE               --defaults=FILE                                 
                        --file-scope                                    
  -s                    --standalone                                    
                        --template=FILE                                 
  -V KEY[:VALUE]        --variable=KEY[:VALUE]                          
                        --wrap=auto|none|preserve                       
                        --ascii                                         
                        --toc, --table-of-contents                      
                        --toc-depth=NUMBER                              
  -N                    --number-sections                               
                        --number-offset=NUMBERS                         
                        --top-level-division=section|chapter|part       
                        --extract-media=PATH                            
                        --resource-path=SEARCHPATH                      
  -H FILE               --include-in-header=FILE                        
  -B FILE               --include-before-body=FILE                      
  -A FILE               --include-after-body=FILE                       
                        --no-highlight                                  
                        --highlight-style=STYLE|FILE                    
                        --syntax-definition=FILE                        
                        --dpi=NUMBER                                    
                        --eol=crlf|lf|native                            
                        --columns=NUMBER                                
  -p                    --preserve-tabs                                 
                        --tab-stop=NUMBER                               
                        --pdf-engine=PROGRAM                            
                        --pdf-engine-opt=STRING                         
                        --reference-doc=FILE                            
                        --self-contained                                
                        --request-header=NAME:VALUE                     
                        --abbreviations=FILE                            
                        --indented-code-classes=STRING                  
                        --default-image-extension=extension             
  -F PROGRAM            --filter=PROGRAM                                
  -L SCRIPTPATH         --lua-filter=SCRIPTPATH                         
                        --shift-heading-level-by=NUMBER                 
                        --base-header-level=NUMBER                      
                        --strip-empty-paragraphs                        
                        --track-changes=accept|reject|all               
                        --strip-comments                                
                        --reference-links                               
                        --reference-location=block|section|document     
                        --atx-headers                                   
                        --listings                                      
  -i                    --incremental                                   
                        --slide-level=NUMBER                            
                        --section-divs                                  
                        --html-q-tags                                   
                        --email-obfuscation=none|javascript|references  
                        --id-prefix=STRING                              
  -T STRING             --title-prefix=STRING                           
  -c URL                --css=URL                                       
                        --epub-subdirectory=DIRNAME                     
                        --epub-cover-image=FILE                         
                        --epub-metadata=FILE                            
                        --epub-embed-font=FILE                          
                        --epub-chapter-level=NUMBER                     
                        --ipynb-output=all|none|best                    
                        --bibliography=FILE                             
                        --csl=FILE                                      
                        --citation-abbreviations=FILE                   
                        --natbib                                        
                        --biblatex                                      
                        --mathml                                        
                        --webtex[=URL]                                  
                        --mathjax[=URL]                                 
                        --katex[=URL]                                   
                        --gladtex                                       
                        --trace                                         
                        --dump-args                                     
                        --ignore-args                                   
                        --verbose                                       
                        --quiet                                         
                        --fail-if-warnings                              
                        --log=FILE                                      
                        --bash-completion                               
                        --list-input-formats                            
                        --list-output-formats                           
                        --list-extensions[=FORMAT]                      
                        --list-highlight-languages                      
                        --list-highlight-styles                         
  -D FORMAT             --print-default-template=FORMAT                 
                        --print-default-data-file=FILE                  
                        --print-highlight-style=STYLE|FILE              
  -v                    --version                                       
  -h                    --help
```

Seems I provided all valid parameters...

**UPDATED:**
I tried to follow commands, but got warning:

```
libreoffice --infilter="source.pdf" --convert-to docx  Settle.doc
Warning: failed to launch javaldx - java may not function correctly
convert /mnt/_work_sdb8/NSN/Settlement/Settle.doc -> /mnt/_work_sdb8/NSN/Settlement/Settle.docx using filter : MS Word 2007 XML
```

and I got empty Settle.docx empty - 4.1 kb
Not sure which options/missing packages in my os I have migconfigured :

```
lsb_release -d; uname -r; uname -i
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
6.2.0-35-generic
x86_64
```

Comment: The new format is an XML-based one known as OOXML. The filename suffix is `.docx` or `.docm`.

Comment: `pandoc` does .docx  Look at: `pandoc --list-output-formats`

Comment: Please read PS2

Comment: Could you please explain why the pdf file is opened in Libre Office Draw application, but not Libre Office Writer as I need? I suppose Libre Office Writer can open and convert pdf into doc(x) file. But It does not in this case. Maybe in my system some configuration options are wrong ? How to check/fix it ?

Comment: @mstdmstd you'll have to go to text file first.  use `pdftotext` like this:  `pdftotext -layout -eol unix your_file.pdf`  Then you will have `your_file.txt` for `pandoc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With distribution packages:

```
libreoffice --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to docx my.pdf
```

or

```
soffice --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to docx my.pdf
```

With TDF site packages:

```
/opt/libreoffice24.2/program/soffice --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to docx my.pdf
```

Comment: When I tried converting my PDF document to odt by modifying the first command, it worked perfectly and I was impressed by the results.

Comment: Please, read UPDATED

Comment: @mstdmstd: NO libreoffice --infilter="source.pdf" --convert-to docx  Settle.doc ???

YES libreoffice --infilter="writer_pdf_import" --convert-to docx source.pdf

Answer (score 0):

From pandoc site, it looks like it is able to convert TO pdf format but not from. So a one in a raw operation doesn't seem to be feasible.
A rough solution would be to convert the pdf file to some text format, and then catch it into OpenOffice. Some trimings may be necessary. But, of course, you know that already ....

Comment: This is not factually correct. I tested converting from PDF to odt using the command in the other answer, and it worked perfectly including the text formatting.

Comment: I just tried the suggested command (with the correct syntax) and, after several warnings in the kind of the ones in the updated question, I got a file which open in draw. Each sentence is like an insert. I tried another example with images which where perfectly reproduced, but the text parts where a set of inserts....